NUnit in Azure Pipelines generating trx files: "No result found to publish"
The problem is as follows:
I've recently come onto a new project and they have 28 unit test projects (using NUnit), many of them still .NET Framework 4.7.2. They have 3 projects upgraded to .NET 6 but now they don't contain test results and they aren't available in the pipeline. When running the build solution locally, it DOES generate the correct trx files locally, however it also doesn't have the correct XML elements.
Here's the error in azure pipelines:

From the pipeline I can download the TestResults zip with all the trx-files and they're all there for the 4.7.2 projects, but these 3 .NET 6 project trx files can't be found, as you can see above.
Here's our YAML configuration regarding Test Results Publishing:
   ## Publish test results
  - task: PublishTestResults@2
    displayName: Publish Test Results
    condition: succeededOrFailed()
    inputs:
      testRunner: VSTest
      testResultsFiles: Pipelines/TestResults/*.trx
      mergeTestResults: true
      testRunTitle: Test run for build $(Build.BuildNumber)
      platform: Any CPU
      configuration: Release

The files DO exist but are missing certain XML-elements like: "Results", "TestDefinitions" and "TestEntries".
Here's an example of an "empty" trx-file:

And here's a correct example from a trx-file from one of the 4.7.2 projects:

As you can see, the "correct" file has the XML-elements Results, etc. The .NET 6 project trx-file doesn't have those elements... Does anyone know why and how I can get those results into the trx-file for the .NET 6 projects? In Visual Studio the tests do run and are working!
EDIT:
Yes, via the VS Test Explorer everything seems to work. However I've found out that by running "dotnet test" in the projects folder itself, it will throw the following errors "error CS0246: the type or namespace name '' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
So my project A references project B that has Nugets installed, and then it complains about project B not having said references to the nugets, but they ARE referenced. The code compiles, builds, etc. But seemingly not so when running "dotnet test" myself in the directory.
And test project A is net6.0, project B is framework 4.7.2 and that references a Nuget, btw.
And e.g. project D (a framework 4.7.2 project) that references project B, DOES work if you run "dotnet test" in it's directory.
EDIT2:
A (net6.0) → B (framework4.7.2) → C (framework4.7.2) that has NUGET packages
⇒ NOK
A (net6.0) → C (framework4.7.2) that has NUGET packages
⇒ NOK
A (framework4.7.2) → B (framework4.7.2) → C (framework4.7.2) that has NUGET packages
⇒ OK
A (net6.0) → NUGETs installed in the net6.0 project
⇒ OK

By In Visual Studio the tests do run and are working, do you mean the test via local VS will generate the correct trx file? if you run dotent build and test for your solution locally, will it generate the correct test results for your .Net 6 projects?

Yes, via the VS Test Explorer everything seems to work. However I've found out that by running "dotnet test" in the projects folder itself, it will throw the following errors "error CS0246: the type or namespace name '' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"
So my project A references project B that has Nugets installed, and then it complains about project B not having said references to the nugets, but they ARE referenced. The code compiles, builds, etc. But seemingly not so when running "dotnet test" myself in the directory.

And test project A is net6.0, project B is framework 4.7.2 and that references a Nuget, btw.
And e.g. project D (a framework 4.7.2 project) that references project B, DOES work if you run "dotnet test" in it's directory.

I've edited my original post with a few quick lines what projects referencing works (OK) and what doesn't (NOK - Not OK) to make it visually easier to understand :)

Hi @Tempuslight, can you please let us know how your solution with sever projects was built? Did you use dotnet build/test or VS Build/test task in your pipeline? Because these are the key steps to generate the test assemblies and test results right? PublishTestResults@2 didn't seem to affect the result contents, since the trx files were already there before publishing.

And if you run dotnet build and dotnet test to build and test your solution via a local command prompt, did it incur any error?

Dotnet build gives the same errors when run locally in the project directory. In the pipeline it uses VSTest. I've changed the pipeline testrunner to NUnit like it says in the documentation of PublishTestResults@2, but that didn't work.
I've also made a new "fake" net6.0 class library, installed the nugets that are causing issues in the above image and imported some code, and then it WORKS! So it seems like if it's a net6.0 test project & class library, then it's no issue (nugets or no). There only seems to be an issue it its net6.0 to 4.7.2.

So the "solution" of our team can be to try and see if we can upgrade all class libraries to net6.0 and then all the tests will run too (we think).

Thanks for taking time to share the update. If possible, would you mind sharing the solution in the answer section below? Cheers.

I've actually found the answer to my issue! I've added an answer to this post.

A .NET Core calling .NET Framework is always a source of trouble.
First thing to try is to convert the .NET Framework projects to .NET Standard (that would be 2.0 I believe). And then see how it goes.
